# Adding a library in Keil as a facade to use C++ inside C project

Tags: c++, c, interop, keil

Because I wanna use some C++ library that I wrote inside my C project I found the facade pattern as a solution for that in another question asked on SO.

I compiled my project containing calculateSensors.h/cpp and facade.h/cpp as a library and included it into my main project. It's just doing some rand function and returning it from a cpp class to test whether this approach is working.

Now the problem is that after including the library I'm not sure how to include and call my functions. I just tried to include facade.h inside the main function (library and main function are in same folder) but the header file is not found. 
What am I doing wrong?
Screenshot attached to better show my problem.

[image: screenshot of my problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the folder in which your `facade.h` resides in to your include path.

In your uVision project configuration in the tab `C/C++`, modify the field `Include Paths` to contain said folder.

Comment: So you mean even if I compile a project as a library, I still need to include header files separately?

Comment: I'm afraid its not working, I'm receiving the error: .\keilFreeRTOS.afx: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol doObjectOrientedStuff (referred from main.o).

Comment: 1. Of course the compiler needs to know the definitions of all the symbols. That's what the header file is for. It therefore also needs to know where wo search for header files that you include in your source code. 2. Undefined symbol means that the linker can't find a binary containing `doObjectOrientedStuff`. So either something went wrong when compiling the library you link against or something went wrong when configuring the linkage of your project to the library.